How can I get the upgrade dialogue to re-appear?
Yesterday I saw a button offering to upgrade to the next LTS. When I connected my laptop to the dock in order to start the upgrade, it closed all windows including the upgrade offer dialogue.
Running the software update check again does not offer a new Ubuntu version anymore. How can I get it to re-appear?
I realize this question looks similar to some that have been asked earlier, but I thought maybe command line upgrade differs from upgrade via GUI.

Try the command update-manager. Is that what you mean?

it may be a blessing in disguise given all the problems recently reported on the upgrade following which the upgrade path was suspended, then re-instated a couple of days ago but people still reporting issues... If you are currently on an earlier LTS, it may be prudent to wait until you get further notification but make sure you have good backups before committing.

This question is similar to: Unable to upgrade from Ubuntu Server 22.04 to 24.04.1. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

"I thought maybe command line upgrade differs from upgrade via GUI." There is no difference.
